# I have some problems with dev/sda in my laptop

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I'm sorry if my question is a bit non suitable with this site, but I really don't know where I should ask it better.

[image]

as you see, there are errors during launching the system (if it's important: ubuntu 14.04), and yesterday I heard some "clicks" when system was running. Now it doesn't launchs at all.

My questions are: what should I do now? what is the cause of this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question might do better on http://askubuntu.com,

but still answering, your hard drive may have crashed (maybe damaged), a good idea would be-

- to boot from a live USB and see if you can detect your HDD (do backup if you can)
- try the HDD on a different computer.

To create a live disk you may see - https://askubuntu.com/questions/172570/how-can-i-create-a-livecd-livedvd-liveusb

to use HDD on a different computer, its better to consult a professional if you have not tried it yourself before.

PS. if you have another desktop handy and are willing to experiment a bit :P

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-an-Extra-Hard-Drive might give you an idea